# Why does my regex find matches on regex testing websites, but not in my program?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-8.0

I'm writing an ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API in C#. This API is supposed to run a CMD line utility and save the output to a text file, which I want to format. The first way I want to format my text file is by applying a regex to overwrite the text file with lines that are matched by my regex.

I've used [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) to test my regex against an unformatted version of my text file and it's matching what it should. However, the solution I've implemented in my program is returning the entire text file instead of just the matches from my regex.

After my text file is being saved, I have two lines declaring a regex pattern and calling a function that is storing the matched text in a variable called matchedLines.

**Note**: I temporarily set a different output location inside the `FilterOutput` function to make sure that my regex is actually matching the text I want. Once I know the regex is working properly, I plan on using the same output location as the original text file.

Here are the two lines:

```
Regex regexPattern = new Regex("""Users of [NXSC]+\d{5}[: ]+\(Total of \d{1,7} licenses? issued;  Total of \d{1,4} licenses? in use\)\n{2}  "[NXSC]+\d{5}" v[\d.]+, vendor: ugslmd, expiry: [\d\w\-]+\n[ \w]+\n{2}( {4}[\w\d .()/,:]+\n){1,999}""", RegexOptions.Multiline);

// filePath is where the text file is being stored
FilterOutput(filePath, regexPattern);
```

And here is the function:

```
private void FilterOutput(string filePath, Regex pattern)
{
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

    List<string> matchedLines = new List<string>();

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        MatchCollection matches = pattern.Matches(line);
        matchedLines.Add(line);
    }

    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines($"output_Directory\\regex_Output.txt", matchedLines);
}
```

Previously, my function looked like this, but the  return data looked the same as the above function.

```
private void FilterOutput(string filePath, string pattern)
{
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

    List<string> matchedLines = new List<string>();

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(line, pattern);
        matchedLines.Add(line);
    }

    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines($"outputDirectory\\regex_Output.txt", matchedLines);
}
```

My variable `matchedLines` somehow contains the entire text file instead of just the matched text. I'm pretty sure my problem lays somewhere in the `FilterOutput` function, but I could use a little assistance identifying exactly what is causing my regex to fail.

**EDIT** You can find a few sample lines from my text file below. This is the type of output I'm expecting to see in `regexOutput.txt`

```
Users of NX43168:  (Total of 6 licenses issued;  Total of 1 license in use)

  "NX43168" v2023.12, vendor: ugslmd, expiry: 01-jan-2025
  floating license

    swesson05 AH641379 AH6413790.0 (v2023.12) (ABCDEFAZU033/13000 33212), start Mon 2/19 12:10
```

```
Users of NX64153:  (Total of 30 licenses issued;  Total of 6 licenses in use)

  "NX64153" v2023.12, vendor: ugslmd, expiry: 01-jan-2025
  floating license

    bspears03 AH641325 AH6413250.0 (v2023.12) (ABCDEFAZU033/13000 701), start Sat 2/17 10:15
    jbieber AH678942 AH6789420.0 (v2023.12) (ABCDEFAZU033/13000 1101), start Sat 2/17 10:15
    jfoxworthy05 AH346759 AH3467590.0 (v2023.12) (ABCDEFAZU033/13000 2501), start Sat 2/17 10:16
    bengvall AH619723 AH6197230.0 (v2023.12) (ABCDEFAZU033/13000 3401), start Sat 2/17 10:18
    giglesias AH619745 AH6197450.0 (v2023.12) (ABCDEFAZU033/13000 72503), start Mon 2/19 12:24
    jdunham AH867530 AH8675300.0 (v2023.12) (ABCDEFAZU033/13000 64701), start Mon 2/19 9:51
```

Comment: You need an if somewhere, currently you're getting the matches from the regex but not doing anything with it. You probably want to do something like `pattern.IsMatch(line)` and only add the line if the line matches the regex

Comment: Could you share sample (or similar) lines of your input so it's easier for us to debug the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Reread your code.

Your code loops through each line of the input, then calls `pattern.Matches(line)` (the result of which is never actually used), and then adds the line to `matchedLines`, regardless of whether the line matched the regex.

```
private void FilterOutput(string filePath, Regex pattern)
{
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

    List<string> matchedLines = new List<string>();

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        MatchCollection matches = pattern.Matches(line);

        // note that there is no conditional here. Every line will be added to matchedLines        
        matchedLines.Add(line);
    }

    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines($"output_Directory\\regex_Output.txt", matchedLines);
}
```

I assume you only want to add the line to `matchedLines` if it actually matches. So you'll want something like this inside the loop:

```
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        if(pattern.IsMatch(line)){
           matchedLines.Add(line);
        }
    }
```

Edit: Your regex is a very complex multiline regex, and so your technique of going through every line and trying to match it will not work, because individual lines can't have linebreaks in them, because then they actually would be 2 lines. I would recommend simplifying your regex, or to search the entire file rather than line-by-line, for example:

```
void FilterOutput(string filePath, Regex pattern)
{
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
    var fileContents = string.Join("\n", lines);
    var matches = pattern.Matches(fileContents);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines($"output_Directory\\regex_Output.txt", matches.Select(m => m.Value);
}
```

Comment: I went ahead and added the if statement, but now nothing is being written to regexoutput.txt?

Comment: That is because your regex is very long and complicated. It requires multiple newline characters, and then you are comparing that regex to individual lines, which cannot contain newline characters (otherwise it wouldn't be a line, it would be multiple lines), so it obviously isn't finding anything. I've changed my answer to include this. I would also suggest in the future thinking more critically about your programming problems before going to stack overflow - both of these issues are very straightforward and could have been solved with a couple of minutes of debugging.